# Getting as.Date to show year only instead of automatically including today's date

Tags: r, indexing, time-series, xts

When I try to create an XTS object using an existing column with years as characters, my xts object automatically included today's date instead of only the year as I specified it. Is there any way to only include the year?

Here's my code:

```
global_totals_ts <- xts(global_totals_m[,-1], as.Date(ts_index, format = "%Y"))
```

and the output that I get is:

```
           Christians    Muslims    Hindus Agnostics Buddhists
1900-05-17  557754602  200318122 202973290   3028610 126956371
1910-05-17  611362430  222347113 223383337   3368564 138064000
1950-05-17  870653646  338066461 323138775 129261500 175510794
1970-05-17 1229448027  570772699 462980539 544290164 234957917
2000-05-17 1987502477 1292170756 822391937 660693376 452314303
2005-05-17 2130604801 1427056087 893077485 669224713 477436475
```

I want the following output:

```
       Christians Muslims    Hindus     Agnostics Buddhists
1900   557754602  200318122  202973290  3028610   126956371
1910   611362430  222347113  223383337  3368564   138064000
1950   870653646  338066461  323138775  129261500 175510794
1970   1229448027 570772699  462980539  544290164 234957917
2000   1987502477 1292170756 822391937  660693376 452314303
2005   2130604801 1427056087 893077485  669224713 477436475
```

thanks very much!

Comment: its not an xts thing. `as.Date('1900', format = "%Y")` does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Date objects will always have days (because dates have days).**

One alternative is to keep it as a date, but floor it by year. Then the dates are always the first day of the year, so that, for instance, `group_by()` operations will be done by year.

```
library(lubridate)

global_totals_ts <- xts(global_totals_m[,-1], floor_date(as.Date(ts_index, format = "%Y"), "year"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Your second solution worked well (and I think I'm going to stick with that), but the first solution couldn't work - I got an error:

    Error in xts(global_totals_m[, -1], year(as.Date(ts_index, format = "%Y"))) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object.


ts_index is a character vector. thanks anyway!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying; I have removed the first suggestion, which was not working.